# MMIO address unmatched in Xv6 operating system?

Tags: c, operating-system, uart, riscv, xv6

I recently found some problems while working on the [Xv6 kernel](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2021/schedule.html). When the kernel booting up, it initializes the PLIC to receive interrupt signals from the UART, but **I found that the address used here is different from definitions in [SiFive_U manual](https://sifive.cdn.prismic.io/sifive/d3ed5cd0-6e74-46b2-a12d-72b06706513e_fu540-c000-manual-v1p4.pdf)**.(Xv6 runs on qemu, which simulates SiFive_ U platform, so I refer to the SiFive_U document...)

For example, when we want to set registers in UART, the kernel set the base address of UART as 0x10000000L:

```c
// defined in Xv6 kernel/memlayout.h:21
// qemu puts UART registers here in physical memory.
#define UART0 0x10000000L
#define UART0_IRQ 10
```

However, the address of UART in the SiFive development manual is not 0x10000000L, **they're 0x10010000L and 0x10011000L instead**, check the image below for more information.

[The UART address in SiFive_U is not 0x10000000L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy9Lj.png)

So **I checked the QEMU source code** and found that the definition in the source code is consistent with the manual:

```
static const MemMapEntry sifive_u_memmap[] = {
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_DEBUG] =    {        0x0,      0x100 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_MROM] =     {     0x1000,     0xf000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_CLINT] =    {  0x2000000,    0x10000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_L2CC] =     {  0x2010000,     0x1000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_PDMA] =     {  0x3000000,   0x100000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_L2LIM] =    {  0x8000000,  0x2000000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_PLIC] =     {  0xc000000,  0x4000000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_PRCI] =     { 0x10000000,     0x1000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_UART0] =    { 0x10010000,     0x1000 },  // UART0
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_UART1] =    { 0x10011000,     0x1000 },  // UART1
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_PWM0] =     { 0x10020000,     0x1000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_PWM1] =     { 0x10021000,     0x1000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_QSPI0] =    { 0x10040000,     0x1000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_QSPI2] =    { 0x10050000,     0x1000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_GPIO] =     { 0x10060000,     0x1000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_OTP] =      { 0x10070000,     0x1000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_GEM] =      { 0x10090000,     0x2000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_GEM_MGMT] = { 0x100a0000,     0x1000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_DMC] =      { 0x100b0000,    0x10000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_FLASH0] =   { 0x20000000, 0x10000000 },
    [SIFIVE_U_DEV_DRAM] =     { 0x80000000,        0x0 },
};
```

Since the MMIO address used in the Xv6 kernel is different from the user manual, how can it successfully access UART? I also compared the addresses of various registers in PLIC and found that the addresses in the Xv6 kernel are also inconsistent with manual.(The base address is the same, but some registers are inconsistent)

Now I'm completely confused:(

I have carefully read the source code and compared it with the addresses in the manual one by one, and found that the MMIO addresses are not consistent. Therefore, I am curious about how the Xv6 kernel successfully controls these devices?

Comment: I noticed that what I should be looking at is the **virt. c** file in qemu. The declared MMIO address in this file is consistent with that in the Xv6 kernel, but the address conversion of registers in PLIC still does not match.